# Eigenvalues of a difference of non commuting products

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ complex matrix and let $T(M) = AM-MA$. I need to determine the eigenvalues of $T$ in terms of those of $A$.

This was an exercise from Artin, and I was not being able to think how to proceed. I couldnot find any proper answer to this on Stackexchange even though I saw this questioned before.

Can you help me? Seems like a good problem. It was listed under the section "Using coninuity" in the chapter "Applications of Linear Operators".

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $T(M) = AM - MA$?  Just curious!  Cheers!

Comment: I think what Robert is saying seems to be correct.

Comment: It's helpful to have the notation $[A, B] = AB - BA$, so that you can write the operator you're interested in as $[A, -]$. For starters, can you solve this problem when $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: Yes, its $T(M)$, sorry. @Qiaochu, I was unable to do it, when $A$ was diagonal. I was getting $T(M)=((a_{ii} - a_{jj})m_{ij})$ but putting it to be equal to $tM$ gives only $t = 0$ from diagonal entries.

Comment: Unless $m_{ii}=0$ for all $i$. In which case, I think we need a common value from $(a_{ii}-a_{jj})$.

Comment: Well, I think I have an answer: Are the eigenvalues $(a_{ii}-a_{jj})= \lambda_i-\lambda_j$ for all $i,j$, by taking appropriate $M$? Now how do I take this to the general case? $A$ may not be diagonalizable.

Comment: I know that diagonalizable matrices are dense in the set of all complex matrices. So somehow if I prove this for diagonalizable matrices $A$, I will be finished by continuity. But how does assuming $A$ diagonal help here? In other words, if this holds for diagonal matrices, how do I conclude this for diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: think about the properties of the trace function

Comment: Well, the trace of any matrix in the image of $T$ is $0$.

Comment: @Qiaochu, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Paramjit: the assignment $A \mapsto [A, -]$ respects conjugation. You also do not need to use a continuity argument: instead of diagonalizing $A$ you can upper-triangularize it and the argument doesn't change much, although you need to think in terms of generalized eigenvectors rather than eigenvectors.

Comment: Okay, I will think about that approach. But it was unclear why on the right side conjugation of $[A,_]$ means anything. I mean this would be a map on the space of complex matrices and conjugation by a matrix doesnot mean anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969714/the-rank-and-eigenvalues-of-the-operator-tm-am-ma-on-the-space-of-matric)

Comment: Is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345661/eigenvalues-of-linear-operator-fa-ab-ba) what you're looking for?