# Eigenvalues of linear operator $F(A) = AB + BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $B$ be the $n \times n$ square matrix; $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n$ are its pairwise distinct eigenvalues. For all $n \times n$ matrix $A$ let me define $F(A) = AB + BA$. We can consider $F$ as a linear operator, because $F(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha F(x) + \beta F(y)$.

What eigenvalues does $F$ have?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've tried to find eigenvectors solving equation $F(x) = XB + BX = \lambda X \Rightarrow XB = (\lambda I - B) X$, however, it didn't help much. Also I've noticed that B is a diagonalizable matrix since it has pairwise distinct eigenvalues, but how can I use it? Finally, I composed the $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, corresponding to this linear operator, it was useless as well.

Comment: Your issue is linked to "Kronecker sum" of matrices and "Sylvester equation". See the reference given in the answer to (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219471/additive-version-of-kronecker-product)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this solution, we only assume that $B$ is diagonalizable (i.e., the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$'s need not be distinct).  If $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are the eigenvectors of $B$ and $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ are the left eigenvectors of $B$, where $Bv_i=\lambda_iv_i$ and $w_i^\top B=\lambda_i w_i^\top$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.  Then, $$
\begin{align}
F\left(v_i w_j^\top\right)&= \left(v_iw_j^\top\right)B+B\left(v_i w_j^\top\right)=v_i\left(w_j^\top B\right)+\left(Bv_i\right)w_j^\top
\\
&=v_i\left(\lambda_j w_j^\top\right)+\left(\lambda_iv_i\right)w_j^\top=\left(\lambda_i+\lambda_j\right)v_iw_j^\top\,.
\end{align}$$  Since the $n^2$ matrices $v_iw_j^\top$, where $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$, are linearly independent, we have found all eigenvectors of $F$.

**EDIT (Due to Request):**

We shall prove that the matrices $v_iw_j^\top$, for $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$, are linearly independent.  Let $K$ be the base field.  Suppose that there exist $\kappa_{i,j}\in K$ for $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}v_iw_j^\top=\boldsymbol{0}_{n\times n}$.  Write $w_j=\left(w_j^1,w_j^2,\ldots,w_j^n\right)$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.  Hence, $v_iw_j^\top=\begin{bmatrix} w_j^1v_i&w_j^2v_i&\cdots&w_j^nv_i\end{bmatrix}$.  Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}v_iw_j^\top=\boldsymbol{0}_{n\times n}$ implies that $$\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}w_j^1\right)v_i & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}w_j^2\right)v_i
&
\cdots
&
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}w_j^n\right)v_i
\end{bmatrix}=\boldsymbol{0}_{n\times n}\,.$$
Consequently, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, we must have $\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}w_j^k=0$, since the $v_i$'s are linearly independent.  That is, $\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_{i,j}w_j=\boldsymbol{0}_{n\times 1}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.  As the vectors $w_j$'s are linearly independent, $\kappa_{i,j}=0$ for all $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$, and the result follows immediately.

**P.S.:**

(1) I think my solution is identical to himbrom's.

(2) This solution works similarly if $F$ is defined via $F(A)=\alpha AB+\beta BA$ for every matrix $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(K)$, where $\alpha,\beta \in K$ are nonzero.  For $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$, the matrix $v_iw_j^\top$ is still an eigenvector of $F$, but with the eigenvalue $\alpha \lambda_j+\beta \lambda_i$.

(3) It would be an interesting problem to see if the converse holds.  Suppose, for fixed $\alpha,\beta \in K \setminus\{0\}$ and for a fixed matrix $B\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(K)$, that $F(A)=\alpha AB+\beta BA$ for every matrix $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(K)$.  If $F$ is a diagonalizable linear operator, then does it follow that $B$ a diagonalizable matrix?  Does the answer depend on $K$, $\alpha$, and/or $\beta$?  For example,
in the case where $K$ is algebraically closed of characteristic $0$, $\alpha=1$, and $\beta=-1$, diagonalizability of $F$ is equivalent to that of $B$ (this is a well known result in Lie Algebra).  If $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$, but not both of them are zero, then $F$ is diagonalizable if and only if $B$ is so.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain please, why are all $n^2$ matricies $v_iw_j^T$  linearly independent?

Answer (score 6):

Let $e_i$ be the eigenvectors of $B$, i.e.
$$Be_i=\lambda_ie_i$$
and let $E_{ij}=e_i e_j^T$ be the elementary matrices in this basis, i.e.
$$E_{ij}e_k=\delta_{jk}e_i.$$
As it turns out, $F$ is already diagonal in the $E_{ij}$-basis:
\begin{align}
&BE_{ij}e_k=\delta_{jk}Be_i=\lambda_i\delta_{jk}e_i=\lambda_iE_{ij}e_k\\
\Rightarrow&F(E_{ij})e_k=BE_{ij}e_k+E_{ij}Be_k=(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)E_{ij}e_k
\end{align}
The eigenvalues are therefore $\lambda_i+\lambda_j$. (Some of them may coincide, for example if you apply the permutation $i\leftrightarrow{}j$.)

Comment: oh that works only for symmetric $B$. @Batominovski 's solution is better.