# linear operator $f(X) = AXB$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> What are the eigenvalues of the linear operator in vector space $M_n(\mathbb R)$ $$ f(X) =  AXA^T $$
>   and $$ f(X) = AXA^{-1} $$
>   when eigenvalues of $A$ are $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n $?

I suspect that in first case is $\{\lambda_i \cdot \lambda_j \ | \  i,j \in \{1,2,3, ..., n\}\} $ and in second $\{\lambda_i/\lambda_j \  |\  i,j \in \{1,2,3, ..., n\}\} $, but I can't prove it.

> More generally what are eigenvalues of $$ f(X) = AXB $$ when we know eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I would start by trying some $2 \times 2$ cases. Make sure you try some non-diagonalisable matrices too, since they can be tricky. This might help better formulate a conjecture about the general case, and illuminate ways of proving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key observation is that you can transform your expressions by using **Kronecker product** (sometimes called **tensor product**) in the following way:

$$f(X)=AXA^T=((A^T)^T \otimes A) vec(X)=(A \otimes A)vec(X)$$

You will find all the details in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product); see in particular the paragraph "Matrix equations" then "Abstract properties : Spectrum".

Same comment more generally for :

$$f(X)=AXB=(B^T \otimes A) vec(X).$$

where $B^T \otimes A$ is a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, and $vec(X)$ is the $n^2 \times 1$ column vector obtained by "piling up" the $n$ columns of $X$.

Comment: If one is interested in the eigenvectors of the map also, observe that if $Ax=\lambda x,$ $B^{T}y=\gamma y,$ then $X=xy^{T}$ satisfies $AXB=\lambda\gamma X.$

Comment: Can I ask why eigenvalues of Kronecker product are products of eigenvalues of matrices?

Comment: See theorem 13.12 of this document (http://www.siam.org/books/textbooks/OT91sample.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**.  I'll use the technique of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345661/eigenvalues-of-linear-operator-fa-ab-ba/1345715#1345715) to answer your question subject to an additional assumption.

**Theorem**.  If $A$ and $B^T$ are $n\times n$ matrices with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors $\def\vec#1{{\bf#1}}\vec v_1,\ldots,\vec v_n$ and $\vec w_1,\ldots,\vec w_n$ respectively and eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$ respectively, then the transformation
$$f:M_n\to M_n\ ,\quad f(X)=AXB$$
has eigenvectors
$$X_{ij}=\vec v_i\vec w_j^T$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_i\mu_j$.

**Proof**.  We have
$$f(X_{ij})=A\vec v_i\vec w_j^T B=A\vec v_i(B^T\vec w_j)^T
  =\lambda_i\mu_jX_{ij}\ .$$
The $X_{ij}$ are linearly independent (see above link), so in particular none of them is zero and they are all eigenvectors.  Finally, we now have $n^2$ linearly independent eigenvectors in a space of dimension $n^2$, so there are no more to be found.

Comment: [+1] Interesting direct approach I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I think we need Jordan structures for the general case