# eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A^TP-PA$ if knowing eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: matrices

I am thinking about the question of the title..

> Suppose we know $Av = \lambda v$ and all eigenvalues of $A$ are different (so diagonalizable). What do the eigenvectors and eigenvalues look like of $A^TP-PA$?

I know that $A^TP - PA$ is a linear map.

Obviously, we can let $A = V\Lambda V^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal. So we have $$(V\Lambda V^{-1})^TP-P(V\Lambda V^{-1}) = V^{-T}\Lambda V^TP - PV\Lambda V^{-1}$$

then how do I go further? I suppose to get a form like $M\tilde{\Lambda}M^{-1}$ and I can say something. How to get that point?

Comment: It might be worth looking at a very simple case, where $A$ is diagonal, and $P$ is the identity. The evals of your matrix are all zeroes in that case, and apparently unrelated to those of $A$.  If $A$ is not diagonal, can you say anything useful about the eigenvalues of $A^t - A$? It's skew-symmetric, so all its eigenvalues are pure imaginary (or $0$). But how are they related to evalues $A$, even in the $2 \times 2$ case? Have you tried working that out?

Comment: Is $P$ a particular matrix, or are you looking at the linear map $P \mapsto A^T P - P A$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Yes I am looking at the linear map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [very similar recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600358/linear-operator-fx-axb) about $X \mapsto A X A^T$.  Coincidence?

The answer is also essentially the same.  If $A^T v = \lambda v$ and $A^T w = \mu w$ are two eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs for $A^T$, then $P = v w^T$
is an eigenvector of your linear map, with eigenvalue $\lambda - \mu$.  If $A$ is diagonalizable, this gives you a full set of $n^2$ linearly independent eigenvectors of your linear map.

Comment: Thanks! just one question, can we think this problem by using the right eigenvector of $A$? (in your case this is a left eigenvector, so right eigenvector of $A^T$)

Comment: Also in this problem, the eigenvector is actually a rank one matrix?

Comment: I don't see how right eigenvectors of $A$ would be useful here.

Comment: And yes, these eigenvectors are rank one matrices.