# If A is diagonalisable then $T\in L(V)$ given by $T(B)=AB-BA$ is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization, invariant-subspace

I wanted to prove that If A is diagonalisable then $T\in L(V)$ given by $T(B)=AB-BA$ is diagonalisable.
My Attempt:
I know that if minimal polynomial of T has distanct linear factors then we can show that T is is diagonalisable.
As A is diagonalisable imlies it has distinct linear factor
I don't know how to give next argument .
ANy Help will be appreciated

Comment: Related thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345661/eigenvalues-of-linear-operator-fa-ab-ba.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that $A$ is already diagonal. Then the matrix units
$E_{ij}$ (the matrices all zero save for one $a$) form a basis of eigenvectors of $T$.