# Finding the Kernel of a Linear Transformation: $T(A) = A M - M A$, where $A, M$ are square matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am interested in a linear mapping of the form
$$
T(A) = A M - M A, \ \ A \in V
$$
where $V = M^{n,n}$.

First, we suppose $n = 2$ and consider a simple numerical problem.

I was solving the problem to find a basis for the kernel of $T$,
where
$$
M = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

So, we take
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

We solve the equation
$$
A M - M A = 0
$$

After simplification, we get
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
-c & a + b - d \\
-c & c 
 \end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
which reduces to two linear equations
$$
a + b = d, \ \ c = 0
$$

Hence, a basis for $\mbox{Ker}(T)$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{B} = \left\{ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
         1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
         1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right] \right\}
$$

Thus, for this example, nullity of $T$ = $2$.

In general, is there any relation between the nullity of $T$ and the rank of $M$
for the mapping (this looks like the Lie bracket)
$$
T(A) = A M - M A, \ \ A \in V = \mathcal{M}^{n,n}
$$

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it

Comment: The question in that exchange was this: "Given a matrix $A$ over a field $F$, does there always exist a matrix $B$ such that $A B=B A$?" In my question, the matrix $M$ is fixed, and $A$ ranges over the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices. If $M = D$ is a diagonal (commuting) matrix, then $T(A) = 0$ for all $A$ and naturally, nullity of $T$ is $n$. Interestingly, rank of $M$ is irrelevant in this calculation... Thanks for this example!! (This could be an answer to my question?)

Comment: *"is there any relation between the nullity of  and the rank of "* No.  The spectrum of $M$ does play a decisive role though. Variations on this have been asked many times, e.g.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969714/the-rank-and-eigenvalues-of-the-operator-tm-am-ma-on-the-space-of-matric?rq=1  . An alternative approach is to view $T$ as isomorphic to $T'\big(\text{vec}(A)\big) = \big(-M \oplus M^T\big)\text{vec}(A)$ and use properties of the Kronecker sum.

Comment: Thank you, I shall read the discussion there!

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626308/942722)